# Is there any evidence of blue jays preying on other birds?

Tags: zoology, ornithology

Are blue jays known to prey on other birds?  I've found that they are known to [raid nests of eggs and young](https://www.allaboutbirds.org/guide/Blue_Jay/lifehistory), but have not found any evidence of them actually preying on other birds.

Background:  A few years ago while raking leaves this time of year (late Oct/early Nov) the head of a house sparrow fell on me.  I looked around in the spruce tree I was under and saw a blue jay eating the rest of the house sparrow.  This was approximately 10 feet from my bird feeders.  I can't say that it wasn't dead beforehand, but it's proximity to the feeders made me wonder.

Comment: I know European Jays kill sparrows if they have an opportunity. So do crows. This is titled blue-jay but it's different than american blue jay. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VmeUcIxLTwk

Comment: @com.prehens.ible.  Thanks for the link.  It is pretty much exactly what I witnessed - including the decapitation.  Unfortunately it starts when it already has the other bird so we don't know if it was scavenged or actively caught.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! [This article](http://benttreevoice.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/usda-fs-bluejay-waxwing.pdf) gives an account of a Blue Jay killing and consuming a Cedar Waxwing, and further it clearly states that at times Blue Jays do predate on fledgling and adult birds, and gives a hefty amount of sources to back that up, if you're in the mood for further reading.

Comment: WOW.  Exactly what I was looking for.